# Creating nodes/turtles out of a shp file from GIS General Examples

Tags: gis, netlogo, shapefile

I need to create nodes from the cities shapefile of GIS general examples, so I can use them as targets for turtles.
I tried the follows solutions but it doesn't work:
http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Creating-nodes-turtles-out-of-a-shp-file-and-linking-them-td5004359.html
http://netlogoabm.blogspot.com/2015/07/loading-gis-and-csv-data-to-model-to-be.html#more

This is the code:

```
extensions [ gis ]
globals [ cities-dataset
      countries-dataset ]
breed [ city-labels city-label ]
breed [ country-labels country-label ]
breed [ country-vertices country-vertex ]

to setup
  clear-all
  gis:load-coordinate-system (word "data/" projection ".prj")
  set cities-dataset gis:load-dataset "data/cities.shp"
  set countries-dataset gis:load-dataset "data/countries.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope (gis:envelope-union-of (gis:envelope-of cities-dataset)
                                                (gis:envelope-of countries-dataset))
end

to display-cities
  ask city-labels [ die ]
 foreach gis:feature-list-of cities-dataset
  [ gis:set-drawing-color blue
    gis:fill ? 2.0
    if label-cities
[ let location gis:location-of (first (first (gis:vertex-lists-of ?)))
  if not empty? location
  [ create-city-labels 1
    [ set xcor item 0 location
      set ycor item 1 location
      set size 0
      set label gis:property-value ? "NAME" ] ] ] ]
end
```

Could someone help me please ?

Comment: could you please provide the code you are using

Comment: Sure but it is so long, so I post it as an answer.

Comment: I moved the code to the question - where it should be - and fixed the tags. You also need to describe the problem. Saying it doesn't work is not useful, does it create an error message, does it put things in the wrong place? Please look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks, but the site didn't let me edit my question.
For the first solution, I modified the code (for countries) just to create the points of edge of countries and adapted it for cities. The code is correct but when I press the button literally nothing happens.
For the second solution, when I check the code it shows a error message "EMPTY? expected this input to be a string or list, but got a turtle agentset instead" and highlights "csv" next to "not empty?"

Comment: There is no "csv" to highlight in the code you have provided. But that error means whatever is following the `not empty?` (location in the code you have provided) is a set of one or more agents. An agentset cannot be tested for empty. If you mean to test whether an agentset is empty, then you actually want `if any?`

Comment: We haven't seen your code for the "second solution". If you want to ask about that code, open a new question and include that code. Otherwise, we're likely to miscommunicate — as just happened with you and JenB.

Comment: As for the "first solution" where "nothing happens", try adding some print statements to your code to get an idea of what's happening. Print out some values and see whether their real values correspond with what you thought they should be. This should help you narrow down the place in your code where something first goes wrong.

Comment: I found another similar solution to write correctly the code and your advices helped me. Thanks a lot.