# How to ask turtles to move over a line which is displayed by importing a shapefile in Netlogo

Tags: gis, netlogo

I want to create turtles that can move on the specified lines in the netlogo world composed of lines (to represent street) and polygons (to represent buildings) by importing a shape file.

Someone else asked this question, but there was no answer: [how to create moving turtles out of a shapefile in Netlogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929504/how-to-create-moving-turtles-out-of-a-shapefile-in-netlogo)

Is it possible in NetLogo or should I use another language?

Comment: Are you working with GIS like the original question?

Comment: I guess you mean [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929504/how-to-create-moving-turtles-out-of-a-shapefile-in-netlogo), I also found [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33846864/creating-nodes-turtles-out-of-a-shp-file-from-gis-general-examples?rq=1).

Comment: I posted my answer in the related question

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929504/how-to-create-moving-turtles-out-of-a-shapefile-in-netlogo/37233573#37233573

Comment: thank you, yes I am trying to work with GIS.